# When I run the example code of openai-java in my machine, SSLHandshakeException error happens

Tags: sslhandshakeexception, openai-api

I tried to run the example of [openai-java](https://github.com/TheoKanning/openai-java), but SSLHandshakeException error happens.

here is my code
[image: my code for this example]

java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at io.reactivex.internal.util.ExceptionHelper.wrapOrThrow(ExceptionHelper.java:45)
at io.reactivex.internal.observers.BlockingMultiObserver.blockingGet(BlockingMultiObserver.java:91)
at io.reactivex.Single.blockingGet(Single.java:2585)
at com.theokanning.openai.OpenAiService.createCompletion(OpenAiService.java:116)

Also, I used postman to send post requests to https://api.openai.com/v1/completions with my secret-key, it gives "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details"

I guess it may because of https Certificate, and I followed [How to Resolve Error message "PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"](https://docs.mend.io/en-US/bundle/wsk/page/how_to_resolve_error_message__pkix_path_building_failed__sun_security_provider_certpath_suncertpathbuilderexception__unable_to_find_valid_certification_path_to_requested_target_.html), and put certificate of https://openai.com/ into my JDK. And It doesn't work. I wanna ask how to fix this problem